# Scaling widget on Android (dp, px, screen size)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

what is the best way for controlling the size of widget on Android?

Look on following table:

• On 3.6-4.0 inch screen (smartphone) with 480x800px the dpi is about **240dpi**
• On 4.3 inch screen (smartphone) with 540x960px the dpi is about **270dpi**
• On 7 inch screen (tablet) with 480x800px the dpi is about **130dpi**
• On 7 inch screen (tablet) with 600x1024px the dpi is about **170dpi**
• On 8.9 inch screen (tablet) with 1280x800/768px the dpi is about **170dpi**
• On 10.1 inch screen (tablet) with 1280x800px the dpi is about **150dpi**

So in general smartphones comes with much higher dpi.

Now if I create a control with 100px width it will be good on low dpi displays but bad on high, where the control will be too small. If I create the same control with 100dp it will be opposite – on high resolution displays it will scale to e.g. 150 px, but on low dpi screens (tablets) it will be still 100px or smaller is the density falls below 160dpi.

So how I should make a control that on 4inch display occupy 1inch on 7inch display occupy 1.5inch and on the 10.1inch display occupy 1inches? In other words – bigger screen size, the bigger is the control, but without considering the resolution.

But is that in fact a good approach?

Regards,
SteN

Answer (score 2):

Please include this in your android manifest file..

```
 <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />
```

and also check the following link from android developer site, this may help you in finding a rite solution for your question..

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Hi, how this will help me? The anyDensity is true by default and resizeable is deprecated, I will support normal, large and xlarge screens - this I will wire into manifest in order to avoid the compatibility mode... I was looking into "Supporting Multiple Screens" document many times, but I did not found an answer to my questions here:((( Might be I have to read it more carefully.