# why the bad font resolution with EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the default [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) control in my app and the font and resolution looks very poor, especially in comparison to whatever DbTextViewer or the Internet/Chrome browser is using, which looks much cleaner.

The app is intended to run on larger-screen device like tablets, and not so much phones.

How do you improve the appearance of the text here?

Here is my app
[image: my app]

DbTextEditViewer looks much nicer 
[image: DbText]

main.xml

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtx"
        android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"      
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26sp"      
     android:textSize="8sp"      
            android:text="save"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question indirectly at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6922397/266457
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html